# Dynamic Array is only returning first element from program

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I'm trying to create a function for school that returns an array where any consonants are doubled (ex. Hello = HHellllo). This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isConsonant(char c) {
    if ((c >=97 && c <= 122 && c != 'a' && c!= 'e' && c!= 'i' && c!= 'o' && c != 'u') | (c >=65 && c <= 90 && c != 'A' && c!= 'E' && c!= 'I' && c!= 'O' && c != 'U')) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

string doubleCons(string i) {
    int len = (int) i.length();
    int numCons = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (isConsonant(i[j]) == true) {
            numCons++;
        }
    }
    int s1count = 0;
    string *s1 = new string[len+numCons];
    for (int j = 0; j < (len); j++) {
        if (isConsonant(i[j]) == true) {
            s1[s1count] = i[j];
            s1[s1count+1] = i[j];
            s1count += 2;
        }
        else {
            s1[s1count] = i[j];
            s1count++;
        }
    }
    return *s1;
}


int main() {

    string s = "Hello";
    s = doubleCons(s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Main is just a test to see if it works. The problem is, the output for main is just H, nothing else.

I've tried looping through s[i] and i just get H????. I can't figure out why the string isn't HHellllo or anything more than H for that matter. Can anybody identify the problem? I've tried debugging with cout statements and I am condiment that isConsonant works fine, as well as the first for loop (numCons = 3 which is correct for hello).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: in this code,

```
string doubleCons(string i) {
    int len = (int) i.length();
    int numCons = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (isConsonant(i[j]) == true) {
            numCons++;
        }
    }
    int s1count = 0;
    string *s1 = new string[len+numCons];
    for (int j = 0; j < (len); j++) {
        if (isConsonant(i[j]) == true) {
            s1[s1count] = i[j];
            s1[s1count+1] = i[j];
            s1count += 2;
        }
        else {
            s1[s1count] = i[j];
            s1count++;
        }
    }
    return *s1;
}
```

the

```
string *s1 = new string[len+numCons];
```

allocates an *array of strings*, instead of creating a longer string.

Instead do something like this:

```
string s1( len+numCons );
```

Yes it’s that simple.

---

In other news:

- It's not a good idea to use the name `i` for anything other than a loop counter, since there's a very strong convention using it for that. And by convention `i` indicates integer. This stems from old Fortran, which got it from mathematics.
- Comparision with `true` is unnecessary and in general an ungood idea (because some C functions return numbers other than 1 to indicate logical true). Consider “I have a house” versus “it’s true that I have a house” versus “it’s true that it’s true that I have a house”, and so on: these comparisons don’t contribute anything useful to the meaning.
- Instead of pre-determining the relevant size and then creating a string of that size, you could simply start with an empty result string and use `push_back` or just `+=` to add characters to the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
return *s1;
```

Compiler would treat this as *(s1+0) i.e only first element.

You should return the pointer.

```
return s1;
```

Accordingly change the signature of function to

```
string* doubleCons(string i) {
```

Comment: He'll also have to loop through the array and print.

Comment: You're missing the point of the code. The OP is not trying to return an array of strings (in which case the practical solution would be to use a `std::vector`). The OP is trying to return a *longer string*.